# Kibana/iframe for dashboard: disable modifications

Tags: kibana

Hellow everyone,

I know I can export my dashboard thanks to the iframe link and to add to my web page. However, it is still possible through my web page to modify my dashboard. I would like to know if there is a parameter inside the url or something else that disables this feature. It would be great for me !!

Thank your for your attention and your help.

Joe

Comment: does anybody have any idea on this subject ?

Comment: You do not have any parameter that doing that, but if it's relevant I can show you the exactly function in kibana code, that doing that and you can set the function as a comment and it's will work

Comment: Yes I do, please show me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK,
Go to kibana/src/ui/public/filter_bar/query_filter.js
search for queryFilter.addFilters function,
mark all function content as comment,
build and restart kibana

Answer (score -1):

Use the link in following way
http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard/My-Dashboard?**embed=true**&_g=(filters:!()

Basically embed=true in your URL will make it read only and remove all extra features.

Comment: This is actually what I am doing. I am importing this url in my website. What I want to disable is when I click on panel i don't want any change (for instance a histogramm with several columns and when I click on a column, the column appears alone. I want to disable that..)